# How to refresh the data in collectionview or tableview only for the update?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How can i only refresh or reload newly added data in collectionview or tableview instead of reload all the data? Right now i am using following code but it query the database sever to get all the data then reload everything. For example i upload only one photo on the sever so i just want to get that photo and reload collectionview only for this newly added photo not load everyting. how can i do that? Thank you!

```
func loadPosts(){

    let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo:PFUser.current()!.username!) 
    query.limit = page
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

        if error == nil {
            self.picArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

         if let objects  = objects{ 
            for object in objects{
                self.picArray.append(object.value(forKey: "pic") as! PFFile)
            }
          }
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        } else{
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
 }
```

Collection view function

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return picArray.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //define cell

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! pictureCell

        picArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in

            if error == nil {
                cell.picImg.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I would recommend moving the image request out of `cellForItem` because it will get called a lot depending on user scrolling behavior, but for now that will work.

You will want to check if the image has already been loaded then use `reloadItems` instead of `reloadData` so your new section in `cellForItem` will look something like:

```
if (cell.picImg.image == nil) {
    picArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in

        if error == nil {
            cell.picImg.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: indexPath) //reload only this item once the image is retrieved
        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```